# Can I legally use mechanics from a game that is removed from the store?

Tags: legal, mobile, copyright

There was a mobile (android, ios) card game that I really liked playing. Last year, the game was removed from the store and noone were able to play it. The company is still up.

That game had a really original Rock-Paper-Scissor battle system. Cards with rock attribute could beat cards with scissor attribute, etc.

Each card had one or more skills to change the board situation slightly so that you can beat the opposing card.

> (For instance, A Paper could turn to a Rock to beat opposing Scissor,
>   if it had the skill ready.)
>
> (As another example, a card could turn all opposing forces to Papers.)

The game had a rare damage mechanic where you lose points according to the cards that lost the battle for you.

The game also had a card crafting mechanic where you could create your own card with selected skills.

Is it legal to copy above mentioned mechanics with a customized art, as a new game? How can I check the laws regarding to that situation? Is there a way to find reliable lawyers in that area?

**Note: I am asking this as a new question because the game is not even in the stores right now. It should make a legal difference in my opinion.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Legal issues are not a matter of opinion, they are a matter of "will this stand up in court?"  Even if a game is no longer sold, copyright law still applies and you can still be sued.  If you want legal advice, ask a lawyer: "an anonymous person on the internet told me that it would be OK" is not a legal defence.

Comment: The problem is, law in my "developing country" is not covering game copyrights. I am not sure which law is responsible for that situation. My country or the original publisher's country?

Comment: I already checked the question you mentioned but could not find answers on "the difference in copyrights of removed games"

Comment: @OnatKorucu if your country does not cover copyright laws, and you plan to sell copyrighted work in that country, what's the problem?

Comment: I will publish from a country that has not concrete laws on game copy rights. But the game will be published globally. Is there a universal court about copyright?

Comment: If you have straight questions about (copyright) law and how it is managed between countries that have such laws and those that do not, maybe [law.se] could help you. I suggest you read their help center first, so that you know if the question is on-topic there, and how to formulate the question.